# How can i use GET_ACCOUNTS in Android Phonegap

Tags: android, api, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've implemented the "http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts" 
api feature in my config.xml file, and i want to use GET_ACCOUNTS function, to get the list of accounts logged in the Accounts Service.
How can I do that in JavaScript?
The PhoneGap documentation is missing this detail although they have the permission for this action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure for which version of Phonegap you are need of this. For version Cordova Ver 2.5, you can use this plugin -

https://github.com/seltzlab/AccountList-Phonegap-Android-Plugin